# contact form php failed

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a problem with my  contact form. When testing it I receive an email with no content. Just empty input titles "from: (empty) Message: (empty)".

PHP CODE

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "mymail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
echo "Thank You!";
?>
```

HTML CODE FORM

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
                        <div class="row 50%">
                            <div class="6u">
                                <input name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" class="text" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="6u">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text" class="text" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row 50%">
                            <div class="12u">
                                <a href="mail.php" class="button alt">Send Message</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing a form because you simply link to `mail.php` with your `<a>`. The way you are doing it, `$_POST` will always be empty as your form isn't submitted.

Please change this line

```
<a href="mail.php" class="button alt">Send Message</a>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="button alt" value="Send Message"/>
```

Comment: Very nice. I also noticed the missing ' " '  :)  ... Now if I want redirect to a thank you html page is this going to do the job ? 
header('Location: contact-thank-you.html'); exit();   I only have to replace echo right?

Comment: That should do the job, yes!